# How to make map rotation smooth in mapbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am trying to rotate a map slowly to a given angle in Mapbox-gl js. I have come across two options for rotating the map, I am unable to find a way to carry out the rotation slowly.

**1. map.rotateTo()**

If I use `map.rotateTo(angle,{duration: 2000})` then I get this error

```
camera.js:1065 Uncaught TypeError: this._onEaseFrame is not a function
    at r.i._renderFrameCallback (camera.js:1065)
    at Oo.run (task_queue.js:52)
    at r._render (map.js:2154)
    at map.js:2317
```

and if I reduce the value of rotation to 0 or 1 the rotation happens quickly/sudendly instead of slowly.

```
var latitude,longitude;
$(document).ready(function(){

  longitude = 17.125359;
  latitude =  56.989567;
  showmap();
});


function showmap(callback){
    mapboxgl.accessToken ='';
    map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center: [longitude,latitude],
        zoom: 17.9,
        pitch: 0,
        bearing: 0,
        container: 'map',
        antialias: false,
        dragPan: false,
        dragRotate: false,
        maxZoom: 18.4,
        minZoom: 17.3
    });

    var geojson = {
            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
            'features': [
              {
                'type': 'Feature',
                'geometry': {
                  'type': 'Point',
                  'coordinates': [longitude,latitude]
                },
                'properties': {
                  'title': 'Mapbox',
                  'description': 'Park '
                }
              }
            ]
          };

    map.on('rotate',function(){
        map.jumpTo({center: [longitude,latitude]});
    });

    map.on('load', function() {
        // Insert the layer beneath any symbol layer.

        console.log("map loaded");
        var layers = map.getStyle().layers;
        console.log(layers);

        var labelLayerId;
        for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
            if (layers[i].type === 'symbol' && layers[i].layout['text-field']) {
                labelLayerId = layers[i].id;
                break;
            }
        }

      rotTest();


});
}


function rotTest(){
 setTimeout(function(){
   if(map != undefined){
     map.rotateTo(180,{duration:2000});
   }
 },5000);
}
```

**2. map.setBearing()**

On using setBearing also the rotation is very sudden. I tried using something like `map.setBearing().setDuration()` but a it results in `setDuration()` not being a defined function.

Since rest of the code is same here is the variation in rotTest() function with `map.setBearing()` function.

```
function rotTest(){
  console.log("Inside rotTest");
 setTimeout(function(){
   if(map != undefined){
     map.setBearing(180);
   }
 },5000);
}
```

Can anyone help me out with how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to handle most situations like this is to use `easeTo`:

```
map.easeTo({
  bearing: angle,
  duration: 2000,
  easing: x => x
});
```